# how to find all string which meet my start and end criteria in apex code

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex

my code is

```apex
String str = 'You can <strong>use a Matcher to find </strong>all matches to a regular repression';
// find all words starting with <strong> and ends with</strong>. 
// RegEx backslash should be escaped with an additional one.
Pattern Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(?i)(<strong>)\\w*(</strong>)');
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) { // find next match 
    String match = m.group();
    result=match+result+'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: You can ask Salesforce questions directly on salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: did you try using `contains` ?